# function varibles not showing up in the inspector unity3d?

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, variables, inspector

I'm trying to make a variable that is a function like there is in the UI button but when I use the code that creates a public action variable it does not show up in the inspector.

```
public Action jumpFunction;
 public Action dashFunction;

void Start()
    {
jumpFunction();
dashFunction();
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Action is not serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize Action for it to show up in editor.